# Local variable not restored on orientation change for fragments in backstack

Tags: android, fragment, android-lifecycle, back-stack

I have two fragments, `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`, the user can go from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB`

Let's say `FragmentA` has a local variable `varA`. When the user is on `FragmentA` and changes orientation I can save that variable with `onSaveInstanceState` and then restore it in `onViewCreated`. No problem there.

However, when the user is on `FragmentB` and the orientation changes, `onSaveInstanceState` is called for `FragmentA`, but `onViewCreated` is never called and the variable is never restored.

How can I restore the variable properly?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but your best choice is usually to have such variables live elsewhere if you want them to persist longer. The owning activity ViewModel is often a good choice. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855873/create-a-shared-viewmodel-with-factory/70857608#70857608) for an example.

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted using ViewModel as you said, and the code feels cleaner. Thank you!
I'm still curious if the way I wanted to do it originally was possible though

Comment: No problem - it's always so much cleaner to have all the state live in the ViewModel and have the activities and fragments just observe the data. I don't know if your original way was possible or not - `onViewCreated` would eventually be called for `FragmentA` when it is displayed, but if you need access to it before it gets displayed that may not be possible.