# I got this bug while tryimg to run my app "Error in Inflating Class Fragment"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp:layout/activity_news: Binary XML file line #25 in com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp:layout/activity_news: Error inflating class fragment                                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp:layout/activity_news: Error inflating class fragment                                                                                            Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
at com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.NewsActivity.getViewModel(NewsActivity.kt:15)                                                                                                 at com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.BreakingNewsFragment.onCreateView(BreakingNewsFragment.kt:29)                                                                           at
```

These are the codes Involved
My activity News Xml

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/newsNavHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Breaking News Fragment

```
class BreakingNewsFragment:Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentBreakingNewsBinding
    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
    lateinit var newsAdapter:NewsAdapter
    val TAG = "BreakingNewsFragment"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentBreakingNewsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setupRecyclerView()
        viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel
        viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            when(response){
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                        newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error ->{
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.message?.let { message ->
                        Log.e(TAG, "An error occured: $message")
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Loading ->{
                    showProgressBar()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun hideProgressBar(){
        binding.paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    private fun showProgressBar(){
        binding.paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView(){
        newsAdapter = NewsAdapter()
        binding.rvBreakingNews.apply {
            adapter = newsAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        }
    }
}
```

News Activity

```
class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news)

        val newsRepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
        val viewModelProviderFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newsRepository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProviderFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        val newsNavHostFragment = findViewById<View>(R.id.newsNavHostFragment)
       bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController())
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using the deprecated `<fragment>` tag. Do you get the same error if you follow the Lint error and replace it with a `FragmentContainerView` and [follow the getting started guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate) to get your `NavController` correctly?

Comment: `viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel` is not the right way to retrieve a view model, and is probably returning null. The relevant error on an inflate error like that is the last one (`lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized`). Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855873/create-a-shared-viewmodel-with-factory/70857608#70857608) for an example of how to get a shared view model in a fragment

Comment: @ianhanniballake it asks for me to setup a navController. I set it up like this Val navController = find a controller(R.id.newsNavHostFragment) setupActionBarWithBarNavController. It stills shows navController not set

Comment: @TylerV I used Val viewModel:NewsViewModel by viewModels() it shows an error that Val cannot be reassign. Which is normal

Comment: @TylerV how do I add it properly

Comment: Did you read the Getting Started guide I linked? It tells you exactly how you are supposed to get the `NavController` instance in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes I did and it shows an error on this code bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController()) that navController has not been set

Comment: That is not what the guide says. Please check it again, read the paragraph, and copy the two lines of code you need.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks I have fixed It, the error came from the way I setup my bottom navigation view.

Comment: Read the link in my comment for an example of how to get the view model